# Do I need to connect my graphics card to my monitor?

Tags: graphics, vga

So I just built a computer and installed the Nvidia Geforce GTX 660. I already connect my computer to the monitor via VGA, but the install manual says that I have to connect my graphics card to my monitor via VGA. Can I just connect it by HDMI or what?

Comment: What manual? I just looked at the installation manual for the [GeForce GTX-660Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/GeForce-GTX-660Ti.pdf) card and it doesn't say anything about connecting to VGA. Besides, it doesn't look like that card has a VGA port. Don't confuse the motherboard manual with the graphics card manual.

Comment: @CharlieRB - His motherboard likely has an integrated video port itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, thank you. I know that but am not willing to assume anything. My comment was to get them to rethink the situation. Too often we jump to the conclusion here that we know all the details when we don't.

Comment: @CharlieRB - I suppose more information is a good idea.  We just have to assume based on the information provided until the user updates their question, with that information which often is never done.

Answer (score 7):

Your motherboard has an integrated VGA port. If you connect your monitor to that port, you are not using your NVIDIA card but the MB's on-board one,

In order to use your card, you **need to connect your monitor to a port on your card**. Since your card has no VGA port, you need to connect your monitor to it either via HDMI or DisplayPort or DVI.

If you are connected via a VGA port, then you are not connected to your graphics card but just to your integrated graphics chip.

Comment: Are you saying that when you add a second GPU to your PC it does not really work since monitor is not plugged into it?

Comment: @Ark-kun it depends on what you mean by "work". You may be using it for calculations, for example, but if you want to see its graphical output you need to connect to it, yes How else could you see its output?

Comment: The OP has stated that they already connected the monitor to the port on the motherboard. Your answer says "If you connect your monitor to that port, **you are not using your NVIDIA card** but the MB's on-board one". You're saying that the card is not used unless the monitor is plugged into it. I'm not sure this holds true since in 2 or 4-GPU systems, most cards are not connected to the monitor, yet they are definitely being used.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [GeForce GTX-660Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/GeForce-GTX-660Ti.pdf), you can connect directly to the HDMI. Page 11 addresses this.

> Connect your computer monitor(s) to the GeForce graphics card using
>   the connectors shown. A single GeForce GTX 660 Ti graphics card can
>   support up to four displays in a multi-monitor configuration.

[image]

As you can see, there is no VGA port, so you must connect to another port. Once you've installed the hardware, you have to install the drivers per the instructions.

Page 21 covers configuring HDMI.

Comment: Funny though, the diagram here has an error. The Displayport connector and the HDMI connector are mislabeled. They should be switched.

Answer (score 1):

If you have VGA and HDMI available, then HDMI would be the preferable option.  It is digital, whereas VGA is analog.

Often you won't notice this but you can get higher resolution and colour depth across hdmi.